# Hardware address of network interface using ioctl on AIX

Tags: hardware, aix, c, network-interface

I want to get hardware address of network interface on `AIX` using `ioctl`.
Like in Linux we get it through:

```
ioctl(sockFd, SIOCGIFADDR, ifr_p);
```

I didn't find `SIOCGIFADDR` flag in `/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h` on `AIX` to get hardware address information.

Is there any way to get it from `ioctl`? or any file in system from where I can get this information like in linux this information is stored in '/sys/class/net/'

Comment: Do you mean IP address, or meant to write `SIOCGIFHWADDR`? (In both cases, try searching for `getkerninfo`.)

Comment: Its SIOCGIFHWADDR, basically I want to get hardware address of network interfaces available on AIX

Comment: Then `getkerninfo` is what you search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of example codes available, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.unix.aix/2aYvFbrPGks/lnodKcXITiEJ) or [here](http://www.samba.org/~tridge/junkcode/aix_getmac.c). Basically, you'll have to call `getkerninfo` with the `KINFO_NDD` argument and then read the address from the `ndd_addr` field of the `kinfo_ndd` struct filled by that call.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked :) just one more clarification getKerninfo works on solaris and HP-UX also?

Comment: No, for HP you'll need the `NETSTAT` ioctl. See [here](http://cplus.kompf.de/artikel/macaddr.html).

Comment: @Philip 
regarding ndd_type, NDD_ETHER or NDD_ISO88023 are for ethernet. Are there any ndd_type for Wlan? I looked in ndd.h but didn't find there any or I might overlooked it

Comment: Actually I want to get all available network interfaces if I don;t filter them using ndd_type getkerninfo will give me network interfaces and also network adapters also. I want to get only network interfaces not network adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily detect a needed include file using something like `grep -w SIOCGIFADDR /usr/include`. This could give not the recommended header file but a deeper one, but at least this will be a clue.

In general, BSD style says the proper header is <net/if.h>. I doubt AIX is changed to make it not work. Also, a convenient wrapper `getifaddrs()` should be available.

Comment: I tried getifaddrs() but ifaddrs.h is not there on AIX

Comment: Did you try searching SIOCGIFADDR in <net/if.h>?